# How to use forloop for variable names

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have variables `text1`, `text2`, `text3`. I want to print them.

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    text = 'text' + str(i)
    print(text)
```

This code prints strings
text1
text2
text3
, not the content of them.

Comment: Don't try to dynamically create variables. That's the wrong way. Use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While I concur with the other comments, there is a way.
But please try to find a better way to do this.

```
for i in range(1,4):
    text = 'text' + str(i)
    print(eval(text))
```

Comment: It would work but please avoid using eval in code op, unless you want huge security holes.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do this is python is to use dictionaries. At the moment you are taking a string object, referenced by the variable text which contains the string 'text' and concatenating it with string object 'i' to make a new string object 'texti' and making the text variable reference that. Ie all you do is make a new string object and reference it with the same variable.

What you want to do is make a dictionary where the keys are the variables and the values contain your referenced objects.

```
variables = {'var1':'Hello', 'var2':'World'}
```

now if you want to get 'Hello' you would

```
print(variables['var1'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do this, try using a list or a dictionary instead.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you need to do this, you can use the function `eval` to parse a string as a python expression. Just replace your `print(text)` line with

```
print(eval(text))
```

But as James Lingham said, this is not a good idea. It's confusing to read and prone to error, and much simpler solutions exist. For example, you could just create a list `[text1, text2, text3]`, and then loop through them.

```
text = [text1, text2, text3]
for i in text:
    print(i)
```